# TFS:The "Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, rdlc

I have a mvc5 web application in TFS server 2013. When I build the solution locally, its working fine. I created a Build definition in TFS and tried to Build, it returned below compiler error.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices.targets (24): The "Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask."

In TFS Server(Microsoft Windows Server 2008), no visual studio is installed. Only .Net framework 4.5.1 is installed. I observed below configuration in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\ReportingServices\Microsoft.ReportingServices

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" AssemblyName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```

Please let me know how to make the build successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have dowloaded ReportViewer.msi and SQLSysClrTypes.msi from below link and installed in TFS server machine and my Build is success without installing Visual studio...
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Comment: for me, it works without the `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` install, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On your build server (which should not be your TFS) you need to install all of the prerequisites for you to build locally.

You will likely need at least Visual Studio and the Reporting Services API components installed. You may need other bits as well.

It's real simple to figure out: What do you need on your developer workstation to build? That's likely what you are going to need on the build server as well.

Comment: "It's real simple to figure out: What do you need on your developer workstation to build? That's likely what you are going to need on the build server as well."                                                I totally agree with you. But without installing Visual studio in TFS server machine, Build is successful before I add reports to my project. I am searching for a component to install which will support Reports(RDLC) without installing Visual studio. Kindly let me know does it exists?